# Counting amount of people in building over time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm struggling in finding a "simple" way to perform this analysis with Pandas:

I have xlsx files that show the transits of people into a building.
Here after I show a simplified version of my raw data.

```
       Full Name                 Time Direction
0  Uncle Scrooge  08-10-2018 09:16:52        In
1  Uncle Scrooge  08-10-2018 16:42:40       Out
2    Donald Duck  08-10-2018 15:04:07        In
3    Donald Duck  08-10-2018 15:06:42       Out
4    Donald Duck  08-10-2018 15:15:49        In
5    Donald Duck  08-10-2018 16:07:57       Out
```

My ideal final result is showing (in a tabular or better graphical way) how the total number of people into the building changes over the time.
So going back to the sample data I provided, I'd like to show that during the day 08-10-2018:

- before 09:16:52 there no one into the building
- from 09:16:52 to 15:04:06 there 1 person (Uncle Scrooge)
- from 15:04:07 to 15:06:42 there are 2 people (Uncle Scrooge and Donald Duck)
- from 15:06:42 to 15:15:48 there is 1 person
- from 15:15:49 to 16:07:57 there are 2 again
- from 16:07:58 to 16:42:40 there is 1 again
- from 16:42:41 to the end of the day there are none

I used real data for that example, so you can see timestamps are accurate to the seconds, but I don't need to be that accurate, since that analysis have to be performed over a 2-months range data.

Any help is appreciated

thanks a lot

giorgio

===============
UPDATE:===============

@nixon and @ALollz thanks a lot you're awsome.
It' works perfectly, apart for a detail I dind't think about in my original question.

Infact, as I mentioned, I'm working with data spanning a period of 2 months.
Moreover, for some reason, it seems that not all the people entering the building have been tracked when exiting it.
So with the cumsum() function, I find the total number of people of a day being influenced by the people of the day before and so on, 
That shows an unjustifiable high number of people into the building during early and late hours of any days apart form the very first ones.

So I was thinking it could be solved by first performing a group_by on days and then appling your suggestion.

Could you help me in putting all together?
Thanks a lot

giorgio

Comment: Please share the actual dataframe instead of an image

Comment: The solution can be simple if your DataFrame is clean. You'd just need to sort by time, map in and out to +1 and -1 and then cumsum. But if you have issues where people leave the building before they enter, or enter multiple times before they leave then it's trickier. Do you have any of those odd cases that you need to protect against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by setting the `Time` column as index, and sorting it using [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Time').sort_index()
print(df)

                Direction      Full Name
Time                                        
2018-08-10 09:16:52        In  Uncle Scrooge
2018-08-10 15:04:07        In    Donald Duck
2018-08-10 15:06:42       Out    Donald Duck
2018-08-10 15:15:49        In    Donald Duck
2018-08-10 16:07:57       Out    Donald Duck
2018-08-10 16:42:40       Out  Uncle Scrooge
```

And create a mapping (as @ALollz suggests) of `{'In':1, 'Out':-1}`:

```
mapper = {'In':1, 'Out':-1}
df = df.assign(Direction_mapped = df.Direction.map(mapper))
```

Which would give you:

```
                   Direction      Full Name  Direction_mapped
Time                                                          
2018-08-10 09:16:52        In  Uncle Scrooge                 1
2018-08-10 15:04:07        In    Donald Duck                 1
2018-08-10 15:06:42       Out    Donald Duck                -1
2018-08-10 15:15:49        In    Donald Duck                 1
2018-08-10 16:07:57       Out    Donald Duck                -1
2018-08-10 16:42:40       Out  Uncle Scrooge                -1
```

Having mapped the Direction column, you can simply apply [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to the result, which will give you the amount of people from a specific time onwards:

```
df = df.assign(n_people = df.Direction_mapped.cumsum()).drop(['Direction_mapped'], axis = 1)
```

Which yields:

```
                       Direction  Full Name  n_people
Time                                                  
2018-08-10 09:16:52        In  Uncle Scrooge         1
2018-08-10 15:04:07        In    Donald Duck         2
2018-08-10 15:06:42       Out    Donald Duck         1
2018-08-10 15:15:49        In    Donald Duck         2
2018-08-10 16:07:57       Out    Donald Duck         1
2018-08-10 16:42:40       Out  Uncle Scrooge         0
```

---

### General solution

A more general solution for the case that not everyone is tracked leaving the building. Lets try with a new df which includes more than one day. Also lets simulate this time that Donald Duck does get in twice, but is not tracked getting out on the second time:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Full Name': ['Uncle Scrooge','Uncle Scrooge', 'Donald Duck', 'Donald Duck', 'Donald Duck',
                                 'Someone else', 'Someone else'],
                   'Time': ['08-10-2018 09:16:52','08-10-2018 16:42:40', '08-10-2018 15:04:07', '08-10-2018 15:06:42', '08-10-2018 15:15:49', 
                            '08-11-2018 10:42:40', '08-11-2018 10:48:40'],
                  'Direction': ['In','Out','In','Out', 'In','In', 'Out']})
print(df)

     Full Name          Time               Direction
0  Uncle Scrooge  08-10-2018 09:16:52        In
1  Uncle Scrooge  08-10-2018 16:42:40       Out
2    Donald Duck  08-10-2018 15:04:07        In
3    Donald Duck  08-10-2018 15:06:42       Out
4    Donald Duck  08-10-2018 15:15:49        In
5   Someone else  08-11-2018 10:42:40        In
6   Someone else  08-11-2018 10:48:40       Out
```

First the previous functionality can be encapsulated in a function

```
def apply_by_day(x):
    mapper = {'In':1, 'Out':-1}
    x = x.assign(Direction_mapped = x.Direction.map(mapper))
    x = x.assign(n_people = x.Direction_mapped.cumsum())\
         .drop(['Direction_mapped'], axis = 1)
    return x
```

And then `apply_by_day` can be applied on daily groups using [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
df = df.set_index('Time').sort_index()
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).apply(lambda x: apply_by_day(x))

                                 Full Name       Direction  n_people
Time       Time                                                  
2018-08-10 2018-08-10 09:16:52  Uncle Scrooge        In         1
           2018-08-10 15:04:07    Donald Duck        In         2
           2018-08-10 15:06:42    Donald Duck       Out         1
           2018-08-10 15:15:49    Donald Duck        In         2
           2018-08-10 16:42:40  Uncle Scrooge       Out         1
2018-08-11 2018-08-11 10:42:40   Someone else        In         1
           2018-08-11 10:48:40   Someone else       Out         0
```

As the resulting dataframe shows, even though was not tracked out leaving the building on the 2018-08-10, the n_people starts from 0 on the following day, as defined function is applied for each day separately.

Comment: Tnx nixon and ALollz for your great help. I updated the question with a "little" problem with my raw data that is preventing me to fully take advantage of your suggestions. Could you please help me another time?

Comment: Okay @GioCo , this should do!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working: 1st i received this error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`, so I think I solved using `pd.to_datetime ()` (but this problem didn't arise with the first solution). 2nd it seems function `apply_by_day(x)` doesn't work at all since the output file i exported is identical to the input file: no column n_people, nor data grouped by time.. any idea? tnx

Comment: It works for me @GioCo , make sure you are using the latest version, I added a change earlier today. I just double checked and it works with this example.

Comment: You were right. It works on my IDE Spyder. The problem is that I was checking the output xlsx file that I created with the command `df.to_excel('Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')` but it doesn't show the df as expected. It's strange since I use that command frequently and without any problem of that kind. Since I have to show the result in xlsx format, could you help me in soving this problem? many thanks

Comment: Not even saving in csv works. I'm testing nixon's solution with the example provided and saving the result with `df.to_csv('nixon.csv', encoding='utf-8')`. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry guys it was totally my fault... I forgot to set this assignment `dfOut = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).apply(lambda x: apply_by_day(x))` and then just `dfOut.to_excel('Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`. Sorry to have bugged you with my last comments, and thanks again for your help